# Does our current understanding of the mass of black hole only allow for it to be located at the singularity?

Tags: black-hole, mass, density, singularity

Does the distribution of mass or density of mass inside the event horizon matter for a black hole to exist as we currently theorize? Could the mass inside the event horizon be distributed in any way at all, or have any density so long as it is dense enough to locate 100% of the mass inside the Schwarzschild radius?

Comment: You could say that but it isn't exactly the same question. That question is basically are singularities real? I'm asking whether there is anything in the math that makes up our current understanding of a black hole that allows for different distributions and densities of mass inside the event horizon.

Comment: Quark degeneracy pressure (if it's existence can be proven) could theoretically sustain the shape of the collapsed core, while balancing the gravitational forces within the object, much like neutron degeneracy does for neutron stars. All while maintaining a radius less than a Schwarzchild radius. But good luck finding a scientist willing to back that up aloud in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a star or neutron star collapses to form a blackhole there will, of course, be a moment when the matter is distributed everywhere within the event horizon.  So, there may not be a singularity within a full fledged blackhole, at first.  But, the inward forces within the event horizon are irresistible (considering that escape velocity is greater than the speed of light) and so everything within the event horizon must fall into a singularity.  How long this takes is complicated by the issue of which reference frame you chose to time it.